# why NSString and NSMutableArray changes behaviour is different?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have NSString type **string1** and **string2**, string2 was assigned as string2 = string1. If string1 was updated with some other value, string2 **WAS NOT** updated accordingly.

```
NSString *string1 = @"hello world";
NSString *string2 = string1;
NSLog(@"string 1: %@", string1);
NSLog(@"string 2: %@", string2);
NSLog(@"===================");
string1 = @"hello world(changed)";
NSLog(@"string 1: %@", string1);
NSLog(@"string 2: %@", string2);
```

However, if I have NSMutableArray type **array1** and **array2**, array2 was assigned as 
array2 = array1. If array1 was updated with some other values, array2 **WAS** updated accordingly.

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray new];
[array1 addObject:@"hello"];
array2 = array1;
NSLog(@"array 1: %@", array1);
NSLog(@"array 2: %@", array2);
NSLog(@"===================");
[array2 addObject:@"world"];
NSLog(@"array 1: %@", array1);
NSLog(@"array 2: %@", array2);
```

I know that for NSString case if I want to make string1 and string2 are always the same, I can make string2 as pointer point to string1, `NSString __strong **string2= &string1;` and for NSMutableArray case I can use `array2 = [array1 copy]` if I do not want array2 to be always same as array1.

But my question is, in my opinion they are both object type and subclass of NSObject. What is the reason for this different behaviour, one is not updating and the other is updating accordingly when have changes?

Comment: Your examples are completely different. With the arrays you are assigning `array1` to `array2` after you change `array1`. But with the strings you assign `string1` to `string2` before changing `string1`.

Comment: Don't: `NSString __strong **string2= &string1;`, it just causes confusion and subverts Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Strings example, both variables are pointing to same memory location. But when you do

```
string1 = @"hello world(changed)";
```

You are not performing any action on string1. Instead your string1 pointer now points to a newly created object.

Whereas, in your arrays example, you performed an action on the array object, which is still being pointed to by both pointers.

In your second example, if you do something like

```
array2 = @[@"new array"];
```

Both pointers will now point to 2 different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%p` to log `string1` like:

```
NSLog(@"string 1: %p", string1);
```

you will see memory address of `string1` changed before and after.
Try it on your `array` too.